# Connecting REST API in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native, class

I am trying to learn how to connect APIs in React Native. I am using a sample API: https://reactnative.dev/movies.json

This is my code:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      dataSource: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch("https://reactnative.dev/movies.json")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.movies,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error)); //to catch the errors if any
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0c9" />
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      let products = this.state.dataSource.map((val, key) => {
        return (
          <View key={key} style={styles.item}>
            <Text>{val}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      });
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>{products.title}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The problem occurs with my "products" variable. In debug mode, I was able to see the `key` and `value` pairs which were correct from the API. However, the products array is populated with objects rather than strings which are structured like this:
`Object {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "RCTView", key: "0", …}`

My code returns the following error: `this.state.dataSource.map is not a function`

EDIT:
The answer below worked for the API I was using. Now I am trying a different API structured like this:

```
{"prods":
    {
    "86400":{"slug":"86400","url":"/86400"},
    "23andme":{"slug":"23andme","url":"/23andme"}
}}
```

I am having trouble with the mapping again. This returns an error:

```
return dataSource.map((val, key) => (
      <View key={key} style={styles.item}>
        <Text>{val.slug}</Text>
      </View>
    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is a small typo in your example. In your component's constructor you specify a `loading` state variable, but in your `render` function you're using `isLoading`. Second, you're not mapping over your data correctly. It just looks like you need to specify what aspects of each movie you care about in your render function. JSX can't handle displaying a full javascript object which is what `<Text>{val}</Text>` ends up being in your code. There are a few ways you can fix this. It's very common to just map over your results and display them directly.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      dataSource: []
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch("https://reactnative.dev/movies.json")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.movies
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, dataSource } = this.state;

    if (loading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0c9" />
        </View>
      );
    }

    return dataSource.map((movie, index) => (
      <View key={movie.id} style={styles.item}>
        <Text>{movie.title}</Text>
      </View>
    ));
  }
}
```

You could also pull this out to a `renderMovies` method, which might help since you are trying to display these in a styled container.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      dataSource: []
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch("https://reactnative.dev/movies.json")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.movies
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  renderMovies() {
    const { dataSource } = this.state;

    return dataSource.map((movie, index) => (
      <View key={movie.id} style={styles.item}>
        <Text>{movie.title}</Text>
      </View>
    ));
  }

  render() {
    const { loading } = this.state;

    if (loading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0c9" />
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.renderMovies()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @anonymous I also created a small code sandbox in case that's helpful. It's in the context of a web app rather than react native, but it shouldn't make too much of a difference in this scenario. `https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-ajax-nv0ew`

Comment: Thanks for your help! Could you possibly look at my edit for a follow-up question?

Comment: @anonymous sure! That response is coming back in the form of an object that is indexed by slug values. Since it's an object, the typical `Array.map` function won't work. Are you using lodash or any other library to provide helper functions? Or, are you trying to do this with vanilla javascript?

Comment: No, I am very new React & React Native so I'm not very familiar with all the libraries. Would you recommend using Lodash?

Comment: @anonymous lodash is a common library to add to projects, but it's all a matter of preference. I've updated my codesandbox with some code and an explanation to hopefully help out. In the sandbox link posted above, check out the `util.js` file. If you want to use plain JS, `Object.values` will be sufficient for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `Object.values()` to restructure the object into an array

```
  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch("https://reactnative.dev/movies.json")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          dataSource: Object.values(responseJson.movies),       //changed this
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simple way. This code uses modern React practice and helps you to brush up your React skills in general. Give a try.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios'; //for fetching data 

export default function App() {
 //React Hook for state
const [ data, setData ] = useState ([]);

//React Hook Instead Of ComponentDidMount
useEffect(() => {
 const fetchData = async () => {
   const result = await axios(
     "https://reactnative.dev/movies.json",
   );

   setData(result.data.movies);
 };

 fetchData();
 }, []);

return (
 <View>
   <Text>{JSON.stringify(data)}</Text>
 </View>
);
}
```